# Search for a value in a python class

Tags: python, list, class, search

I have a list of customers (just three at the moment) and each customer will have a unique code. I want to be able to be able to search for the customer, using what input received; address, first name or second name. If multiple values are stored within the last e.g. two kims - both should be returned. I have included my code below but process finishes with no return. Can anyone show me where I am going wrong with my code and point me in the right direction? Why is it not taking the input, searching through the list and returning a value? Please see my code:

```
all_customers = []

class Customer:
    customers = []

    def __init__(self, first, last, address):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.address = address

    @staticmethod
    def search_members():
        print()
        user_input = input("What customer are you searching for? ")
        print()

        for i, customer in enumerate (all_customer):
            if user_input in all_customer:
                print("Test", customers)


customer_1 = Customer('Kim', 'N', 'London')
customer_2 = Customer('Chris', 'E', 'Japan')
customer_3 = Customer('Gill' 'T' 'London')
```

Comment: You have two lists, and your customers aren't in either of them. Why would they be?

Comment: `all_customer` or `all_customers`?  note that your list is empty, this is so wrong...

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare the user input string to customer objects. Instead you need to check if the user input is in one of the customer fields. The `result` list below will contain all the customers that have an exact match on user input for the first name, last name or address.

```
class Customer:
    all_customers = []

    def __init__(self, first, last, address):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.address = address
        Customer.all_customers.append(self)

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return f'{self.first} {self.last}'

    @staticmethod
    def search_members():
        print()
        user_input = input("What customer are you searching for? ")
        print()

        result = [c for c in Customer.all_customers
                  if user_input in (c.first, c.last, c.address)]

        print(f"Matching customers: {', '.join(c.full_name for c in result)}")


customer_1 = Customer('Kim', 'N', 'London')
customer_2 = Customer('Chris', 'E', 'Japan')
customer_3 = Customer('Gill', 'T', 'London')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just override the `__eq__` method, so that two customers compare equal if they share a field. `list`'s `__contains__` method uses equality to find out if it contains an element:

```
class Customer:

    def __init__(self, first, last, address):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.address = address

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.first == other.first or self.last == other.last or self.address == other.address

customer_1 = Customer('Kim', 'N', 'London')
customer_2 = Customer('Chris', 'E', 'Japan')
customer_3 = Customer('Gill', 'T', 'London') # fixed the commas

customers = [customer_1, customer_2, customer_3]
Customer('Kim', 'G', 'Berlin') in customers
# True
```

The alternative is to have a class to hold your customers and override its `__contains__` method:

```
class Customers(list):
    def __contains__(self, x):
        return any(x.first == y.first or x.last == y.last or x.address == y.address for y in self)

customers = Customers([customer_1, customer_2, customer_3])
Customer('Kim', 'G', 'Berlin') in customers
# True
```

The latter is probably preferred, because having different customers compare equal might be a bit dangerous.